# I accedently deleted the trashcan icon for the desktop (I accidentally selected remove from desktop when I right clicked) how can I get it back?

Tags: raspbian, linux

I tried to fix it but I am new to raspberry pi/Linux stuff so I have no idea what I did...
Please help

Comment: Rigth click on desktop → Desktop prefs → Desktop Tab → check the Wastebasket box. If already checked try to uncheck, close pref., open prefs. check the box again ?

Comment: You may always delete things without using a trash icon by typing `rm fileToRemove.txt` from the terminal, for example. **Make sure you're in the proper directory before typing this or it may delete something undesired**. To open a terminal in which you can type that, open the file viewer, navigate to the folder in which the file to delete is found, then press `F4`. You'll be able to type the `rm fileToRemove.txt` now.

Answer (score 3):

`Rigth click on desktop` → `Desktop prefs` → `Desktop Tab` → `check the Wastebasket box`